# Having trouble returning the correct values for one element in this function

Tags: jquery, get, set

I'm having trouble getting the `'var hasLining'` function to work properly. It should return "0" or "1", depending upon if there is a lining.  I can't figure out why, but it is causing the function to always return the wrong answer (I'm not sure exactly what's happening, but it looks like it's giving the value for the next equation).

I've posted a fiddle to demonstrate the problem: [jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/9NKjT/1](http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/9NKjT/1)

```
var isThickerFabric = function() {
  var item = $("[name=Item]").val();
  return item == "Blazer" || item == "Jacket" || item == "Outerwear";
}
var hasLining = function() {
  var lining = $("[name=Lining]").val();
  return lining != "0";
}

$("[name=Item],[name=Fabric_Type],[name=Lining]").change(function(){  
  if ( $("[name=Fabric_Type]").val() === "Satin" ) {
    var fabricThicknessElement = $('[name=Fabric_Thickness]');

    if ( isThickerFabric() && !hasLining || !isThickerFabric() && hasLining ) {
      fabricThicknessElement.val('2');
    } else if ( isThickerFabric() && hasLining() ) {
      fabricThicknessElement.val('3');
    } else {
      fabricThicknessElement.val('1');
    }
  }    
});
```

Comment: you do not set the value of 'Lining' text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var hasLining` function check whether `[name=Lining]` has value "0" or not, its always return true when `[name=Lining]` field is empty or any value other then 0, it will return false when its value is 0,

that's why its always get the value of `fabricThicknessElement` 3 because its always get a true form `var hasLining`

if you want to get result on the bases on whether the lining is empty or not. Change  `var hasLining`

`return lining != ""`

and also change the condition  to

`if ((isThickerFabric() && !hasLining()) || (!isThickerFabric() && hasLining()))`

Comment: That worked :-D Would you mind explaining to me the format you used 'return lining != ""', so that I'll know how to apply it to other situations?